# SentencepieceでBPEを訓練する際にどうしても0（UNK）が発生してしまう

Tags: python

タイトルの通りです
Sentencepieceをmodel_type=bpeで訓練を行いました。
corpus.txtはプロによる校正済みの日本語文書です。一行あたりに一文が書かれています。
文章の総数は約200,000文です。

```
import sentencepiece as spm
spm.SentencePieceTrainer.Train('--input=corpus.txt --model_prefix=index --vocab_size=32000 --model_type=bpe --max_sentence_length=200000 --character_coverage=1.0')
sp = spm.SentencePieceProcessor()
sp.Load("index.model")
sp.EncodeAsIds("総務省は地方自治体に向けて改善案を提出した。") #著作権の都合により適当な文章を入力としています
sp.EncodeAsPieces("総務省は地方自治体に向けて改善案を提出した。")
```

訓練に使用した一部をIDに変換したところ以下のようにUNKを指すIDが発生しました。

```
[12667, 28077, 15866, 25464, 0, 21805, 0, 19801, 21301, 27760, 0, 23969, 0, 31770, 19800, 0]
['▁', '総', '務', '省', 'は地方', '自', '治体に向け', 'て', '改', '善', '案を', '提', '出', 'し', 'た', '。']
```

UNKを発生しないようにするにはどのような処理が必要でしょうか。

追記:
sentencepieceのversionを確認したところ0.1.83でした

Comment: 訓練に使ったコマンドやコードと、ID変換で実行したコードを載せてください。

Comment: 申し訳ありません。実行したコードを全て記載しました。

Comment: できれば、著作権に反しないような適当な文字列を入力して問題が再現するか確認し、それを貼っていただけないでしょうか。その上で、EncodeAsPiecesの結果も表示していただけると問題を把握しやすくなります。

Comment: お手数おかけします。適当な文字列でのID出力とEncodeAsPiecesの追加をしました。

Comment: 文章の多くには「。」が入っているはずなので、「。」がunk扱いされるのはおかしいですね。corpus.txtはまさか形態素解析によるトーカナイズ済みのデータではないですよね？

Comment: corpus.txtはトーカナイズされていない生文のデータです

Comment: character_coverageを0.9995などに設定しても同じ結果になるでしょうか？

Comment: character_coverageを1にする前に一度その条件でやったのですが、その場合でも同様に様々な部分でUNKが発生しました

Comment: JESCというデータを用いて訓練し、同じ文に対してテストしてみましたが、unkは存在しませんでした。```[3518, 12114, 26197, 11252, 26306, 26687, 26370, 8349, 6439, 24385, 26933, 1335, 26220]
['▁総', '務省', 'は', '地方', '自', '治', '体', 'に向けて', '改善', '案を', '提', '出した', '。']
```

Comment: sentencepieceのバージョンを```spm_train --version```で確認し、それを質問文内に貼っていただけないでしょうか。pythonのsentencepieceモジュールのバージョンも```pip freeze | grep sentencepiece```で確認して貼っていただけるとありがたいです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

可能性として、データの問題か、あるいはsentencepieceの問題があります。

JESCというデータを使って検証する場合、以下を実行します:

```sh
wget https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/jesc/data/split.tar.gz
tar xzvf split.tar.gz
cd split
cut -f2 train > train.ja
```

```py
import sentencepiece as spm
spm.SentencePieceTrainer.Train(
    '--input=./split/train.ja --model_prefix=index --vocab_size=32000 --model_type=bpe --max_sentence_length=200000 --character_coverage=1.0'
)
spm.SentencePieceTrainer.Train(
    '--input=./split/train.ja --model_prefix=index2 --vocab_size=32000 --model_type=bpe --max_sentence_length=200000 --character_coverage=0.9995'
)

sp1 = spm.SentencePieceProcessor()
sp1.Load("index.model")

sp2 = spm.SentencePieceProcessor()
sp2.Load("index2.model")

print(sp1.EncodeAsIds("総務省は地方自治体に向けて改善案を提出した。"))
print(sp1.EncodeAsPieces("総務省は地方自治体に向けて改善案を提出した。"))
print(sp2.EncodeAsIds("総務省は地方自治体に向けて改善案を提出した。"))
print(sp2.EncodeAsPieces("総務省は地方自治体に向けて改善案を提出した。"))
```

[出力]

```py
[3518, 12114, 26197, 11252, 26306, 26687, 26370, 8349, 6439, 24385, 26933, 1335, 26220]
['▁総', '務省', 'は', '地方', '自', '治', '体', 'に向けて', '改善', '案を', '提', '出した', '。']
[3518, 12114, 28791, 11252, 28900, 29281, 28964, 8349, 6439, 24385, 29527, 1335, 28814]
['▁総', '務省', 'は', '地方', '自', '治', '体', 'に向けて', '改善', '案を', '提', '出した', '。']
```

EncodeAsIds内の文は任意です。

もし、このスクリプトの実行によってunkがなくなったのであれば、問題はデータにあった可能性が高いということになります。データの問題としての可能性は、

- データが少ない。
- corpus.txtがutf-8ではない。
- データがトーカナイズされている。
- データ内に印字不能文字等、なんらかの不正な文字が含まれている。

などがあると思います。

しかし、これでもunkが出るのであれば、問題はsentencepieceにある可能性があります。その場合、sentencepieceのgithubページを確認し、最新バージョンに対して正しい方法でコンパイル・インストールを行ってください。
https://github.com/google/sentencepiece

詳しい回答を希望する場合、sentencepieceの公式のgithubページからissueを投稿すると良いでしょう。

Comment: 記載していただいた内容をそれぞれ試したところutf-8になっていなかったことが原因でした。全てutf-8に直したところ正しく動作しました。